# К 11-ти это какой промежуток времени?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, стилистика, общие-вопросы

К 11-ти означает то, что человек должен прийти в районе 10:30-11:00 или после 11-ти?

Comment: Для справки: в количественных числительных буквенные наращение не используются. Правильно: "К 11 часам". Но: "К 11-му часу".

Answer (score -1):

К 11:00 – может, прийти должен в 10:50 или 10:55